# add www alias to site subdomains

Tags: linux, apache, dns, dreamhost

I want to add www alias to my subdomains such that www.subdomain.domain.com, points to the same content as subdomain.domain.com

In my DNS record I currently have the following 
A  --mysiteip--
sudomain1 IN CNAME domain.com.
subdomaine2 IN CNAME domain.com.

www IN A --mysiteip--

In my Apache config I create virtualhosts for each subdomains, wehre I have the following in each hosts : ServerName subdomain1.mysite.com
                ServerAlias www.subdomain1.mysite.com

When I access subdomain1.mysite.com, I get served the proper content.

I tried adding www.subdomain1 IN CNAME domain.com. in my DNS record, which does not seem to be working. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: That should work, perhaps your DNS entry is in correct.  Try doing a ping to www.subdomain1.domain.com and see if the right IP resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was indeed correct. I just needed for the DNS to propagate, which took longer than usual.